# My Cocos2D lags at a few hundred simple CCDrawNodes -- just drawing lines

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I lose framerate around 300. I expected to have more on screen since it's just drawing lines.

What kind of OpenGL settings or drawing code do I need for more performant drawing?

I have Thumb support disabled.

```
//Bullet.m

@implementation Bullet

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    [self drawSegmentFrom:ccp(0,-1) to:ccp(0,1) radius:1 color:[CCColor blueColor]];
    return self;
}
```

to be clearer: Under 60 at 300. At 400, it flickers between 51 & 60 fps.

Comment: a few hundred = a lot ... consider that a single ccdrawnode is supposed to contain all of your lines, not one per line because then you'll get "a few hundred" draw calls

Comment: I'm testing with enable batch processing. I had to add this to the header in CCDrawNode. Tests on Simulator are faster, will test on device shortly.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D ah, I've been using CCDrawNode like I use a CCNode -- as a game object. Enable batch processing drastically speeds things up. It looks like you're suggesting to only use a single draw node, however?

Comment: I've got a few hundred bullets I want to draw in my game. " 
 @warning If you need to just change a single primitive, you have to clear the draw node, and re-add all existing primitives that you've
 stored somewhere, with the changes applied. This is of course inefficient, hence the recommendation to use this node primarily for debug drawing. */". Is batch processing the solution? Is there a more right way?